# How to searching and change XML if needed?

Tags: c#, xml

I got XML like this:

```
 <Type> 
   <Connections>
      <Conn ServerName="serv1" DataBase="Persons" User="admin" Pass="123"/>
      <Conn ServerName="serv2" DataBase="Type123" User="admin" Pass="123"/>
   </Connections>
   <UDLFiles />
 </Type>
```

so I load the xml like this

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
```

and I have given a combination of ServerName, DataBase, User and Pass.

How to check in the XML if I have already added this combination as a `<Conn>` (those are 4 attributes) and how to add it if I havent added it yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option (if you are using .Net 3.5 or higher) is to skip XmlDocument and use LINQ to XML which, in my opinion, results in cleaner code:

```
// Load the XML from file
XElement docElem = XElement.Load(path);
// Get the Connections element. This code assumes there will always be exactly one.
XElement connectionsElem = docElem.Elements("Connections").Single();

// Check if there is already a Conn element with the required attribute value combination
if (!connectionsElem.Elements("Conn").Any(connElem =>
    (string)connElem.Attribute("ServerName") == serverName &&
    (string)connElem.Attribute("DataBase") == dataBase &&
    (string)connElem.Attribute("User") == user &&
    (string)connElem.Attribute("Pass") == pass)) {

    // Otherwise add such a Conn element
    connectionsElem.AddFirst(
        new XElement("Conn",
            new XAttribute("ServerName", serverName),
            new XAttribute("DataBase", dataBase),
            new XAttribute("User", user),
            new XAttribute("Pass", pass)
        )
    );
}

// Write the XML to file again.
docElem.Save(path);
```

Comment: there are no method like XElement.Elements().Any()

Comment: Any() is a Linq extension method so you need to make sure you have a using statement for the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath.

`xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("\Type\Connections\Conn[@ServerName='" + strServerName + "' and @Database='" + strDbName + "' and @User='" + strUser + "' and @Pass='" + strPass + "']");`

The result will be null if there isn't one, and will be the `Conn` node if there is.
I've used arbitrary variable names to represent the values of the fields you're looking for here. Obviously there's other ways of formatting your XPath, such as `string.Format(..)`; it's up to you how you generate your XPath.

Adding one's less trivial:

```
XmlNode connections = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("\Type\Connections");
XmlElement newConn = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Conn");
newConn.SetAttribute("ServerName",strServerName);
// (repeat for remaining attributes)
connections.AppendChild(newConn);
```

I'm writing this code from memory, so the precise syntax/method names may be slightly different.